# How to get fixed size key from user input

Tags: c#, padding, tripledes

Just want to know, If I use `TripleDES` encryption (`keysize` (168)192bits) and ask the key from the user and the user gives a key which might be more or less in size compare to actual size of the cipher then what should I do? Should I just add 0s or 1s using `String.PadLeft`  or `String.PadRight` to the key? Is there any built in methods/idea/library/tricky codes to add random strings to the key? If so, then is it possible to reverse the process?

I was hoping to use hashing algorithm but .Net doesn't support any  hashing algorithm with output size 192bits. So is there any solution to this?

This simple code is to make it more clear: (encryption part only)

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Plain Text: ");
        string original = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter The Key: ");
        string keyString = Console.ReadLine();
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(original);
        byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(keyString);
        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider myTripleDES = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] encrypted = EncryptString(data, key, myTripleDES.IV);
        string encrypt = Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
        string decrypted = DecryptStringFromBytes(encrypted, key, myTripleDES.IV);
        Console.WriteLine("encryted: " + encrypt);
        Console.WriteLine("decrypted: " + decrypted);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }



    static byte[] EncryptString(byte[] data, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {


        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdsAlg = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        tdsAlg.BlockSize = 64;
        tdsAlg.KeySize = 192;
        tdsAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        tdsAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        tdsAlg.Key = Key;
        tdsAlg.IV = IV;
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = tdsAlg.CreateEncryptor(tdsAlg.Key, tdsAlg.IV);
        byte[] encrypted = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("The Cipher length: " + encrypted.Length);
        return encrypted;
    }
```

This code will not work until I give (valid) fixed size key input. And my question is what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You need to use a [Key Derivation Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function), [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx) (aka PBKDF2) is one built in to the .net framework.

Comment: whats a salt? and can it be user given?  Is there any fix size for it?

Comment: A salt is a large random number that you store but not necessarily need to keept secret. It is to make sure two people who use the same password does not create the same result. That way if you have a database of hashed passwords you can't tell if two users used the same password. It serves the same job a IV does when you are encrypting.

Comment: Thanks. I being curious, is there any other way or more built in classes like this?

Comment: There is `PasswordDeriveBytes`, which is the deprecated, faulty predecessor of `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`. `bcrypt` and `scrypt` or the OpenSSL `EVP_BytesToKey` are not build into .NET by default to my knowledge. The functions are all called Password Based Key Derivation Functions (PBKDF's).

Comment: I forgot to say this problem was solved by myself. I should have answered it. but anyways Thanks :)